# Rstudio script editor not highlighting syntax errors

Tags: rstudio

My Rstudio script editor does not show syntax errors.

[editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD7kY.jpg)

[diagnostic setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHwCc.jpg)

Comment: Welcome! Have you done any web searches for this issue? It seems likely that Rstudio documentation or a forum would have answers.

Comment: i read and followed the Rstudio documentation.  I did not see any answers on the forum.

Comment: Syntax errors will not show until you save the script in R